# Java Domain Classes fill with data

Tags: java, mocking

I have some domain classes and i want to init and fill those classes with sample **hardcode** data , is there any method which i can fill data with any framework ?

For Example :  `List<Customer>` should be filled with some mock data

Comment: So your looking to use a framework to create a dynamic mock implementation of your own custom object?

Comment: You can take a look on MockNeat: https://github.com/nomemory/mockneat . It should be quite handy to create a list of Customer(s) with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider maintaining your test data in a JSON structure, and use a framework (e.g. [google-gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)) to deserialize the data into value objects.

If you wish to auto-generate random data, you might want to look into something like [Quickcheck](http://java.net/projects/quickcheck/pages/Home), which seems to be Java's equivalent of the .NET framework [Autofixture](http://autofixture.codeplex.com/).

Comment: thanks this is a good eye opener  , do u have any suggestions where i can store the the JSON ?

Comment: Where it is most convenient. Could be external files, could be in the constructor of the tests.

Comment: i like this approach even something like mongodb should be work

Comment: Updated my answer with another suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your hard-coded data in a constructor.

If it's mocking frameworks that you are after (as you indicate in comments), then take a look at e.g. [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/).

Comment: actually i need lists not for a single class :)

Comment: Are you domain classes lists of objects? What kind of data do you need? Where and how are you constructing your lists? With more information, you might get more useful answers.

Comment: Thanks @ipavlic , i have domain classes such as customer , user etc.. and i need to like hardcode the data layer of these domain objects , to create some recordsets , to fill the application with data

Comment: @Sudantha Sure, but where exactly do you need it? You might just construct your Customers, Users with hardcoded data and put them in a list.

Answer (score 1):

1. As @ipavlic wrote, you might make your constructor generate some random data when the object is created.
2. You may store the data in a DB or a simple text file and read it from there when you fill your list.
3. You may combine aproach 1 and 2 and store possible field values in a file or somewhere else and fill the Object fields with these randomly chosen predefined values.

Comment: hi thanks , if i goes to option two what you recommended ? hibernate ?

Comment: Hibernate should be simple enough to maintain some tests. As for me, I prefer to deal with pure JDBC.

Answer (score 1):

If you want fill list of Customer, there is this method [Collections.fill(java.util.List, T)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#fill%28java.util.List,%20T%29) to fill list. This method replace current objects in list. If list is empty it won't fill.